# MSBuild script fails but produces no errors

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a MSBuild script that I am executing through TeamCity.

One of the tasks that is runs is from Xheo DeploxLX CodeVeil which obfuscates some DLLs. The task I am using is called VeilProject. I have run the CodeVeil Project through the interface manually and it works correctly, so I think I can safely assume that the actual obfuscate process is ok.

This task used to take around 40 minutes and the rest of the MSBuild file executed perfectly and finished without errors.

For some reason this task is now taking 1hr 20 minutes or so to execute. Once the VeilProject task is finished the output from the task says it completely successfully, however the MSBuild script fails at this point. I have a  task directly after the VeilProject task and it does not get outputted. Using diagnostic output from MSBUild I can see the following:

My questions are:

- Would it be possible that the MSBuild
  script has timed out? Once the task
  has completed it is after a certain
  timeout period so it just fails?
- Why would the build fail with no
  errors and no warnings?

[05:39:06]: [Target "Obfuscate"] Finished.
[05:39:06]: [Target "Obfuscate"] Saving exception map
[05:49:21]: [Target "Obfuscate"] Ended at 11/05/2010 05:49:21, ~1 hour, 48 minutes, 6 seconds
[05:49:22]: [Target "Obfuscate"] Done.
[05:49:51]: MSBuild output:
  Ended at 11/05/2010 05:49:21, ~1 hour, 48 minutes, 6 seconds (TaskId:8)
  Done. (TaskId:8)
Done executing task "VeilProject" -- FAILED. (TaskId:8)
Done building target "Obfuscate" in project "AMK_Release.proj.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:12)
Done Building Project "C:\Builds\Scripts\AMK_Release.proj.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (All target(s)) -- FAILED.

Project Performance Summary:
    6535484 ms  C:\Builds\Scripts\AMK_Release.proj.teamcity.patch.tcprojx   1 calls
              6535484 ms  All                                        1 calls

Target Performance Summary:
      156 ms  PreClean                                   1 calls
      266 ms  SetBuildVersionNumber                      1 calls
     2406 ms  CopyFiles                                  1 calls
    6532391 ms  Obfuscate                                  1 calls

Task Performance Summary:
       16 ms  MakeDir                                    2 calls
       31 ms  TeamCitySetBuildNumber                     1 calls
       31 ms  Message                                    1 calls
       62 ms  RemoveDir                                  2 calls
      234 ms  GetAssemblyIdentity                        1 calls
     2406 ms  Copy                                       1 calls
    6528047 ms  VeilProject                                1 calls

Build FAILED.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 01:48:57.46
[05:49:52]: Process exit code: 1
[05:49:55]: Build finished

Comment: Try running msbuild with maximum verbosity to have more info on assembly references with your projects. (msbuild [ProjectFile.proj] /v:d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the .exe is not returning standard exit codes then you may want to specify to ignore the exit code when using the [Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) task with IgnoreExitCode="true". If that doesn't work then try the additional parameter IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat="true".

Comment: I changed from using the task to running it via a exec command. This gave me an actual error. Once I sorted the error out, it worked a treat. Thanks for your help.